# Determine whether the function $f(x)$ is of order $2^x$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove $$  f(x) = 2^x +  x^2 $$
It is of the order $2^x$ or $f(x)$ is of the order O($2^x$). So far I've got,

$$|f(x)| = 2^x + x^2 \le  |2^x|  +  |x^2|  =  2^x + x^2 \le 2^x + 2^x$$

I have no idea how to get this to become just $2^x$ or if I am even doing this right. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know whether $2 f(x)$ is $O(f(x))$?  What does the big "$O$" mean?

Comment: You don't have to make it into $2^x$. Note that the definition of $O(2^x)$ gives you another piece to work with.

Comment: @Arthur can you elaborate?

Comment: @Zevias Read the definition of $O$ one more time. You will see that $f(x)\in O(2^x)$ doesn't mean $f(x)\leq 2^x$. It means something a little different. And that little extra is exactly what you need to finish the proof here. Also, $2^x+x^2\leq |2^x|+|x^2|\leq 2^x+x^2$ looks a bit unnecessary.

Comment: @Arthur I still am not sure what to do. I reduced it further to 2 2^x so that means f(x) is O(2^x) with witness C = 2 and witness K = (-infinite, +infinity)?

Comment: Apart from the fact that for $x<4$ we mostly have $x^2>2^x$. So the interval where your reasoning holds is $[4,\infty)$ (as well as on the interval $(-0.767,2)$, where $2^x$ is also larger than $x^2$, but that's not very relevant). Yeah, that's it. Problem solved. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

Following the definition, can you find constants $M$ and $C$ such that for all $x>M$,

$$2^x+x^2< C\,2^x\text{ ?}$$

In other words,

$$1+x^22^{-x}< C.$$

By a quick study of the function $1+x^2e^{-x}$, we see that it is decreasing for $M\ge3$. As the value at $3$ is $1+\dfrac98$, we have for instance

$$x>3\implies 2^x+x^2\ge3\cdot2^x.$$

We illustrate this on the plot below, where the vertical axis is logarithmic:

[image]